# What are all the equations we use to calculate how bounces work?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, collision

I mean, what is the  object's final displacement, or the function that describes the object's height over time (see **[1]**) of an object thrown by a height $h$ with a speed of $\vec{v_0}$, a mass of $m$, a "bounce factor" of $\Lambda$ and the floor with a friction of $F_f$ and the air with a friction of $F_a$.

**[1]**

> [image: Bounces]

Comment: What is a "bounce factor"?  Is it a percentage of energy lost in the bounce?

Comment: @JerrySchirmer I put it into "" because I don't know what is it, but there must be something like that. A percentage of the energy lost in the bounce _maybe_.

Comment: It's called the [coefficient of restitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_restitution), but anyway... I don't think this question is well formulated because it's not about a physical concept, you're just asking for a list of equations (which, by the way, can be found in any intro mechanics textbook as well as on thousands of websites, including probably about a dozen Wikipedia pages alone). I'm not sure it really warrants closing, so I won't (for now), but could you try explaining what research you've done and/or what you've tried and what you're still looking for afterwards?

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky If you put here one single link with this explanation, I'll close the question. I don't find anything relevant.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: The coefficient of restitution is the answer--- why not post it as such?

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: While I do agree that this is sort-of-borderline-too-localised, I don't think that this is easily solved via The Google. I've never really seen lists of usable formulae anywhere, and if the OP needs this for, say a game, then finding _all_ the relevant formulae will be tough.

Comment: @RonMaimon: Not just the coefficient of restitution. I'll post a detailed answer later.

Comment: @QMechanic I wouldn't say its homework, or homework-like.. More of 'general reference'.

Comment: @Manishearth: lists of formulas aren't really what this site is for, though. That's more of a Wikipedia thing. (Sometimes it's OK if the list is fixed, very specific, and can be enumerated in a single definitive answer) But the bigger issue is that there doesn't seem to be any prior research involved in this question. Garmen1778, if you had mentioned that you had checked a textbook or two, or Wikipedia or other websites, and that you weren't able to understand or find the information you needed, I would have much less reason to complain and it likely would have been a quite decent question.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: Makes sense. In this case, the formulae _can_ be enumerated pretty easily (my answer got a bit long because I don't like giving derived formulae without fundamentals). Also, gleaning these formulae from a textbook is pretty hard--you _have_ to completely understand momentum first. But I agree that the OP should have indicated that he'd tried to look for them first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've also answered a similar question [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/25342/14272).

### Variables

I'm using the subscript $y$ to denote stuff in the perpendicular direction (along the $y$ or $h$ axis), and $x$ for stuff in the parallel direction (along $x$).

I'll use $u$ for initial velocities and $v$ for final velocities. The initial and final refer to "just before/after a bounce", and "just before/after an arc", where "bounce" refers to the moment when it touches the ground, and "arc" is the arcing motion afterwards.

$e$ is the coefficient of restitution--this is the "bounciness" you wanted. It can have any value from 0 to 1, where 0 is completely unbouncy(inelastic), and 1 is very bouncy.  (elastic). A value greater than one gives an unphysical effect where it bounces higher. It's related to energy via $\text{loss in energy} = \frac12mv^2(1-e^2)$, for a ball bouncing on the ground. So I guess $\Lambda_\text{(percentage of energy loss)}=1-e^2\times100\%$

$\mu$ is the friction coefficient for the ground-ball interface. It is 0 for a frictionless surface, and usually less than 1. Not necessarily, though. It will lead to an additional loss of energy not taken into account by $e$ or $\Lambda$.

$g$ is gravitational acceleration

Note that all the quantities are signed.

### Relevant formulae, condensed version

#### **For a bounce**

$$v_y=-eu_y$$
$$v_x=u_x+ \mu(e-1)u_y$$

These $v$s become $u$s for the upcoming arc.

Bounces are pretty much instantaneous. If you want to consider the time factor, you need to know the shape and young's modulus of the object.

#### **For an arc**

The arc will be executed in a time $t_{arc}=2u_y/g$, and will attain a maximum height $y_{max}=\frac{u^2}{2g}$

During this time:
($t$ is the time since the arc started, NOT the total time)
$$y=u_y-\frac12gt^2$$
$$x=u_xt$$

At the moment the arc finishes,

$$v_x=u_x$$
$$v_y=-u_y$$
These $v$s become the $u$s for the next "bounce"

### All the forumulae

#### SUVAT equations

See [suvat-equations](/questions/tagged/suvat-equations). In this case, $a_y=-g,a_x=0$, and $s$ is distance travelled in relevant direction. You can apply these equation separately for $x$ and $y$.

#### Bouncing

Here, $N$ is normal force. $f$ is  the friction force. $J$ refers to impulse, $p$ to momentum.
**Friction**
$$f=\pm\mu N \text{ direction can vary}$$
**Impulse**
$$J_y=\int N\rm dt$$
$$J_x=\int f\rm dt$$
We can combine these to get $J_x=\pm\mu J_y$
We take the sign $-$ in this case, as friction opposes motion, and the motion in $x$ direction is positive.

$$J=\Delta p=m(v-u) \text{ for both axes}$$

Combining all these, you can get the bounciness equations.

Note: if you want your ball to have a spin as well, the equations become more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a combination of projectile motion and restitution/collision equations for a simple model.  Model each bounce individually using projectile motion eqs. for trajectory and for each bounce collision, use restitution/collision equations to calculate the angle of launch for the next bounce as well as initial energy/velocity.